# ByteArray to SQLite in Android

Tags: sqlite, bitmap, arrays, blob

I try to put a ByteArray to a `SQLite` Database:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

byte[] photo = baos.toByteArray();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("unterschrift", photo);

myDBAuftrag = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MAMActivity.MY_DB_AUFTRAG,
    this.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

int anz = myDBAuftrag.update(MAMActivity.MY_DB_OELSPUR_TABLE,
            cv,
          "aktiver_datensatz = ?",
          new String[]{
           "1"
         });

myDBAuftrag.close();
```

When I show the database in Sqlitehelper on my windows pc, i have in the field only a little pices of my ByteArray like this: �PNG
What i'm making wrong.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

The problem seems to be that your helper program is not able to display PNG images in blob fields.
If you read the data back with `cursor.getBlob()`, it will come out fine.

Comment: thanks, yes it seems so. I have try call the data back with your help and it is in the db. Just i must view the image in BirtReport. But that is another question. Thanks a lot